# How to connect or install redis for session management on digitalocean app platform?

Tags: redis, digital-ocean, session-storage, session-management, digital-ocean-apps

I have deployed a Golang app on digitalocean app platform. The Go app utilizes redis for session management.Everything seems to be running smooth except when I try to login it logs an error `sessions: invalid character in cookie name:` which I've come to notice it's due to the absence of redis-server or redis in general as I've tested my local project by shutting down the redis-server and it gives the same error I get on digital ocean app platform. My question is... How can I setup redis on digital ocean when using app platform? Do I install?..How? or I've to pay $15 for managed redis database on digitalocean for just keeping user sessions? Please any advice is appriciated as I'm newbie to digitalocean but I'm pretty familiar with linux so don't fear to advice me choosing my own droplet over app platform if your opinion falls there.

Comment: Are you using Docker? If yes, then you can create a local redis db using docker composer

Answer (score 0):

Digital Ocean has excellent tutorials on Redis Server install

For example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-redis-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Thanks dude it's a very useful tutorial! But according to my question is that I've deployed my app on digitalocean app platform and not on a droplet. This gives a number of questions on how to install redis server in the scenario where they manage the underlying infrastructure for me i.e I do not I have access to the underlying machine so I could get a chance to install redis or something else?

Comment: Oh.  There are hosted Redis services available both from Digital Ocean and other providers ;)

Comment: Please could provide a link to any?

Comment: As I work for one, I don't feel comfortable steering you in any direction, but a search should be able to provide some results for you to evaluate